# php login page, cannot log in

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i created a log in on my php, but cant seem to find the bug. need help finding it. below is my code:

my login.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['U_Name']) && isset($_POST['U_Pass'])){

$user = $_POST['U_Name'];
$pass = $_POST['U_Pass'];


if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE U_Name = '".$user."' AND U_Pass = '".$pass."'") or die (mysql_error());

        $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        $test = $data['U_Pass'];

        $query_run = $query;
        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

            if($query_num_rows == 0){


                echo "Invalid username/password";

                }

            else if($query_num_rows == 1){


                echo "ok";
                $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'id');
                $user_id = $data['U_ID'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." ");
                }
            {
        }

    }
else{

    echo "You must supply a username and password";

}

}

?>

<div align = "center">
<form action ="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method = "POST">
Username : <input type = "text" name = "username"> Password : <input type = "password" name = "password">
<input type = "submit" value = "Log in">
</form>
</div>
```

and connection.php:

```
<?php


$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("Can't connect : ". mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('users', $dbc) or die ("Can't connect : ". mysql_error());


?>
```

whenever i input my username and password it would only just return to my login page. nothing happened, not even an error message. please help me. thanks

Comment: Where are you getting `U_Name` and `U_Pass` from?

Comment: Major case of [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) and eventual hacking with [**MD5**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Comment: i have a seperate php to minimize sql injection

Comment: Good, but that won't help your using MD5.

Comment: haha i used md5 so it would look good, nothing more haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are getting wrong post fields it must be same as form input fields name try to change

```
if(isset($_POST['U_Name']) && isset($_POST['U_Pass'])){

$user = $_POST['U_Name'];
$pass = $_POST['U_Pass'];
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```

cause if you using

```
<input type = "text" name = "username"> 
<input type = "password" name = "password">
```

then getting data on post looks like:-

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```

**Note**:- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Also use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to esacpe input strings

Answer (score 1):

you set one names for input fields in html:

<input type = "text" name = "**username**">

<input type = "password" name = "**password**">

but reading from

$user = $_POST['**U_Name**'];

$pass = $_POST['**U_Pass**'];

you have to use the same names in HTML and during reading from $_POST, and it is not related how your columns named in database

Comment: Please don't use code like that. I edited your answer for a reason. You've already made your point.

Comment: Your source code looks like this `&lt;input type = "text" name = "**username**"&gt;

&lt;input type = "password" name = "**password**"&gt;`

Comment: My point is that, pre-formatted code that looks like code and shows syntax highlighting, "sells" better. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- my point was to show names, with code formatting this information is lost

Comment: I know what you mean, don't get me wrong, emphasis is good. However, if you compare the amount of upvotes that the accepted answer has gotten, you'll see that others may not think the same way you do. I get it, but others won't. I'm just saying.